# Battleships game, replace grid with character issues

Tags: c#

I'm currently trying to create a battleships console application. I've very new to c# but I'm almost there now there's just issue.

What I'm trying to do is replace a string with H or M when a ship is hit the works fine the only issue I have is when the H or M is inserted it doesn't replace the character in its place and it just moves the characters alone, for example if I have 5 characters in a row it like so: 0 0 0 0 0 it would insert the H or M and show: M0 0 0 0 0

I've been trying all sorts to fix this but as I said my knowledge is very limited.

Ints and Grid creation:

```
        int gridSize = 10;
        int BattleShip = 5;
        int Destroyer1 = 4;
        int Destroyer2 = 4;
        int Row;
        int Column;
        char[,] Vgrid = new char [gridSize, gridSize];
```

This generates the grid:

```
            for (Row = 0; Row < gridSize; Row++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("{0} | ", GridNumber++);
                for (Column = 0; Column < gridSize; Column++)
                    Console.Write(Vgrid[Column, Row] + "~ ");
            }
```

This code controls the H or M replacing:

```
            if (grid[temp, temp1] == Destroyer1 || grid[temp, temp1] == Destroyer2 || grid[temp, temp1] == BattleShip)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("HIT!");
                Hit++;
                Vgrid[temp, temp1] = 'H';
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("MISS!");
                Miss++;
                Vgrid[temp, temp1] = 'M';
            }
```

Is there a way I can do this? I just want to be able to replace the character in the grid with the H or M characters.

This grid is actually an overlay as the actual grid is an int and that is where the ships are plotted, this is the only way I thought I can use letters to signify a hit instead of numbers and keep the ships hidden to the players.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attempting to alter the output of the Console window directly isn't necessarily the best approach for what you're wanting to achieve. Ideally, we should control what we write to the window, rather than try and control the window directly.

A simpler idea to achieve your goal might be to store two grids, one for your ships and another one for your shots. This allows you to separate what you draw to the console window from what you use to check if the player has landed a shot easily, keeping your ships hidden.

Firstly, let's create our setup:

```
    int gridSize = 10;
    int BattleShip = 5;
    int Destroyer1 = 4;
    int Destroyer2 = 4;
    int[,] shipGrid = new int[gridSize, gridSize];
    char[,] shotGrid = new char[gridSize, gridSize];
```

The big change is the grids - one for the ships, and another for the shots. We use the same gridSize variable to make sure that the grids are exactly the same size. This is important to make sure that the two grids line up exactly.

Then, we'll set our default values for our shotGrid. We can do this with a simple method that just sets every value to the default, in this case '~':

```
    public void CreateShotGridDefaultValues ()
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < shotGrid.GetLength(1); y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < shotGrid.GetLength(0); x++)
            {
                shotGrid[x, y] = '~';
            }
        }
    }
```

Next, to check if a player has landed a shot, we use the shipGrid to check if the player's selection relates to a ship, but we update the shotGrid with the information we want to draw to the console window:

```
    public void CheckPlayerShot(int xCoordinate, int yCoordinate)
    {
        if (shipGrid[xCoordinate, yCoordinate] == Destroyer1 || shipGrid[xCoordinate, yCoordinate] == Destroyer2 || shipGrid[xCoordinate, yCoordinate] == BattleShip)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("HIT!");
            Hit++;
            shotGrid[xCoordinate, yCoordinate] = 'H';
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MISS!");
            Miss++;
            shotGrid[xCoordinate, yCoordinate] = 'M';
        }
    }
```

Then, we draw out the shotGrid to the console window as follows:

```
    public void DrawGrid()
    {
        Console.WriteLine();

        for (int y = 0; y < shotGrid.GetLength(1); y++)
        {
            string currentLine = $"{y + 1} | ";

            for (int x = 0; x < shotGrid.GetLength(0); x++)
            {
                char shot = shotGrid[x, y];

                currentLine += shot.ToString() + " ";
            }

            Console.WriteLine(currentLine);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

This method is a little different to yours, so let me explain a little further. The idea for this method is to build up the information we want to write to the console window one line at a time, rather than draw out every character one at a time. This prevents us from needing to change the console window output directly.
To achieve this, we use two loops, just like you did. The second for() loop iterates through the row's grid cells, and adds them to the currentLine string. Once we've finished a row, we just write out that string to the console window all at once.

With all that in place, you just need call the DrawGrid() method whenever you want to update the grid in the console window. To better understand when and where the best time and place to update the window might be, requires a better understanding of Game Loops. [This page should be a terrific start on that path.](https://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html).

Edit: Updated answer to reflect comments.

Comment: This is great, I already started doing something along these lines but I couldn't get it to work, I will try this now and hopefully it will fix my issue really appreciate it

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still having issues, when it generates the grid for example I see ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ and then if I insert H or M it shows M~ ~ ~ ~ ~. I want it to replace the ~ with the M or H so It will show M ~ ~ ~ ~

Comment: @ItsOliMate try changing this line `currentLine += shot + "~ ";` to this... `currentLine += shot + " ";`

Comment: Still having the same issues, although this time instead of being H~ ~ ~ ~, every time I select a new coordinate it moves the others along, I'm guessing this is adding a space and then not removing one so It keeps getting longer

Comment: Thanks, @ItsOliMate. I've updated the answer. I believe I mistook the "~" character as some kind of separator. I can now understand you want that character to be the default value. As such, we need to handle things a little bit differently.

Comment: @DonTickner Thanks so much for this, that is now replacing it which is great. Just one more question, I'm trying to put a space between each ~, when I try to change it an error appears saying too many characters in character literal, do you know how I can change this?

Comment: Hi @ItsOliMate. The error you're getting is probably because you changed the line to something like "shotGrid[x, y] = ' ~ ';" to add in the spaces. The error you're getting is because there is a difference between "~" and '~', with the single quote version being the declaration of single character.
The best way to do what you're asking to is in the DrawGrid() method. I've updated the answer with the change you need.

Comment: Thats perfect, all sorted now. Really appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

[Console.SetCursorPosition(Int32, Int32) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.setcursorposition?view=netframework-4.8)

> Sets the position of the cursor.

Or you could just keep everything in a matrix and redraw the screen on change

Comment: _"...Or you could just keep everything in a matrix and redraw the screen on change"_   **THIS** is a great idea!!!

Comment: Thanks for this, so if I use the set cursor position what would this do to the code and where would I put this in the code?

Comment: or what would be the best way to redraw the grid?

Comment: Just redraw the whole thing every time. You can clear the console programmatically, so draw your grid, then draw your input prompt underneath. When input is read, do your processing then redraw it all again.

Comment: This is included in a while loop, wouldn't this already redraw it?